# How to write delete room tables in database with list<collections>?

Tags: android, android-room, dao

I need to delete a list of subroutines with one button push. But when I wrote in dao

```
@Delete(entity = Subroutines.class)
    void deleteSubroutineList(List<Subroutines> subroutine);
```

I keep getting errors trying to setup up the repository for AsychTask

```
public void deleteSubroutineList(List<Subroutines> subroutines) {
    new DeleteSubroutineListAsyncTask(habitWithSubroutinesDao).execute(subroutines);
}

public static class DeleteSubroutineListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Subroutines>, Void, Void> {

    private final HabitWithSubroutinesDao habitWithSubroutinesDao;

    public DeleteSubroutineListAsyncTask(HabitWithSubroutinesDao habitWithSubroutinesDao) {
        this.habitWithSubroutinesDao = habitWithSubroutinesDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<Subroutines>... lists) {
        habitWithSubroutinesDao.deleteSubroutineList(lists);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Required type:** List,

**Provided:** List<Subroutines>[]

But when I update required type on dao into

```
@Delete(entity = Subroutines.class)
void deleteSubroutineList(List<Subroutines>[] subroutine);
```

I get error at compile: pointing on dao

```
error: The partial entity java.util.List<E> does not have any columns that can be used to perform the query.
    void deleteSubroutineList(List<Subroutines>[] subroutine);
```

The Subroutine Entity Class:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
                entity = Habits.class,
                parentColumns = "pk_habit_uid",
                childColumns = "fk_habit_uid",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ))
public class Subroutines implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pk_subroutine_uid")
    private long pk_subroutine_uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "fk_habit_uid", index = true)
    private long fk_habit_uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "routine")
    private String subroutine;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "color")
    private String color;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "isModifiable")
    private Boolean isModifiable;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "isMarkedDone")
    private boolean is_marked_done;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "streak")
    private int streak;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_streak")
    private int total_streak;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "skips")
    private int skips;
```

*not include getter and setters, constructor, toString cause to long

What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you could utilise:-

```
@Delete(entity = Subroutines.class)
void deleteSubroutineList(List<Subroutines> subroutine);
```

In conjunction with :-

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<Subroutines>... lists) {
        for(List<Subroutines> ls: lists)
        habitWithSubroutinesDao.deleteSubroutineList(ls);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I followed your suggestion on dao and was able to fix it by doInBackground without iterating through the list.

Comment: ```habitWithSubroutinesDao.deleteSubroutineList(lists[0]);```